# strange effect/flicker in jQuery stop() in rollover menu

Tags: jquery

I've made this site with a jQuery rollover menu:

http://www.ffsolar.com/index.php?lang=EN&page=home

It happens that it is not working well. Please try to move your mouse rapidly from the white space over the button "Services" down to the middle of the image. A strage effect happens, the menu starts to "flicker" and won't stop until you move your mouse out.

Well this is my jQuery code:

```
$('#main_navi li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop(true,true).slideDown(200);
       }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop(true,true).slideUp(200);
        }
    );
```

Can someone explain me why this happens and what I can do about it? I've tried all combinations of true and false in stop(), but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not really nail it down, but it appears to me, that it is timing issue. What happens when you move the mouse really fast over it, is, that your menu item get the mouseover event, it expands the menu, but before the menu is expanded, it will receive the mouseout event a little bit later and collapses it, but because the mouse is now over the expanded menu, it receives a mouseover again (I'm not really shure on this one, because it seems strange, that mouseover/out events are dispatched even if the mouse is not moved).
Keep in mind that the browser dispatches mousemove events each few milliseconds, not for every pixel it moves. Likewise are mouseover and -out events not necessarily dispatched at exactly the time they actually occur. If my assumptions on the event-frenzy are correct, it should be solvable with a `stop()` before the sildes, though you said you've already tried that. This way the slides should immediately retract on a mouseout.

**Edit** Made a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qZUsE/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, but isn't this the correct way things should be done? How else could I have done this rollover menu in jQuery? Do you think that a change in the milliseconds could fix the problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this way, I'd have done it the same way. As I said, you should replace `stop(true, true)` with `stop(false, false)` or simply `stop()` (which is the same, [see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)). That way the flicker should go away, because the menu would nicely retract itself from the current extent on a mouseout. If you use `stop(true, true)` you don't stop the slideDown on a mouseout, which causes all the trouble. Maybe it even works, if you just omit the `stop` completly.

Comment: If I use just `stop()` the submenu doesn´t open anymore after doing what i have described with the mouse. So i just deleted the `stop()`. Just check out what happens now... Or what happens if you move the mouse rapidly over the different menu items. That's exactly the effect I wanted to avoid with the `stop()` method. Is there anything I could do about this? Thanks again for your help, i appreciate it very much!

Comment: I made a jsFiddle (see answer), to show you how I meant it to be. In my opinion, it is completely fine to not open - or just partially open - the menu if you just move in and out of it fast. This situtation doesn't occur that often. And if you open every menu that was ever hovered (I guess this is what you meant), how do you want to close it if the mouse is already out of it? Move over and out again is not really a satisfying solution, this would rather cripple than help the user experience.

Comment: That solution is exactly what I'd like to achieve, it's perfect! But when I try this on my site, it doesn't work. I think you got it wrong, when I use the `stop()` on my site, after moving the mouse rapidly over a button, it never opens its sub-menu again until I reload the whole page. And I don't get why, because I'm doing everything as you did in the example, but for me it does not work... (I can't show it to you because then the users couldn't use the site anymore)

Comment: You are right, it only works in jQuery 1.7.2, but not before, not even in 1.7.1 (you are using 1.6.4 as I see). If you can, update to 1.7.2. I can't really see why the effect isn't correctly reset in the versions before.

Comment: Wow! It works now exactly as I want! I would have never thought that this is a matter of the jQuery version... Thank you so much!